# What Direct/Indirect Object Pronoun Is Used With Vos (Colombia)?

Tags: gramática, pronombres, voseo

When using the informal *vos*, is it more common to substitute it with *le* or *te* as an object pronoun? Or is there another standard way to replace it? And I'm curious how this may vary by country or region.

For example:

> Y vos, ¿que le/te pasó?
>   A vos le/te gusta andar en bici.
>   Le/te regalé el libro a vos.

Comment: I might've written the first example incorrectly and it could be "Y a vos" instead of "Y vos." But in spoken Spanish, "Y vos" seems like it would sound fine.

Comment: The first one should be *Y a vos* (it would be *y a usted/ti* with other pronouns).  I can't speak for Columbia, but the norm with informal voseo is to use *te*.

Comment: We'll have to wait for someone from Colombia, but I'm *voseante* and I always use *te*. The only Colombian *voseo* I've ever heard comes from watching *Narcos* (sorry) and I'm sure that used *te* with *vos* as well.

Comment: I think you should always be able to use "os",  am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Only te can be used with vos.

For a more formal way :"Le" (without vos)

Comment: In Colombia would you use *vos* to speak to your boss?

Comment: No, vos is the same as tu, you should use "usted" and "le".

Comment: The question was whether you should use *le*, *te* or something else when the pronoun is *vos*.  Your answer implied that *le* is used for *vos*, but *te* can also be used for *vos*.

Comment: You can only use te with vos

Comment: this answer seems unclear, first you say to only use `te`, next you say you can use  `le` for a more formal approach, I believe you are missing the fact that `le` would go with `usted` instead of `vos`

Comment: I haxe simpli,fied if,